# Looping through Array of Arrays in Ember

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js

I'm bit new and confused about Ember iterations.

I'm trying to construct a **select** inside ember template, like:

```
<select id="state_list">
  {{#each stateArrays as |stateArray|}}
    <option value={{stateArray[0]}}>{{stateArray[1]}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

Here, `stateArrays` looks like:

```
[[1, "Alabama"], [2, "Alaska"], [3, "Arizona"]]
```

But, this throws error. When I try `{{stateArray}}`, I get string like `"1, Albama"`...

How to achieve the above in single iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the array of arrays into an array of objects:

```
mappedArray = [[1, "Alabama"], [2, "Alaska"], [3, "Arizona"]].map(function(array){
    return { num: array[0] , str: array[1] };
})
```

Then you can use it as:

```
<select id="state_list">
    {{#each mappedArray as |obj|}}
        <option value={{obj.num}}>{{obj.str}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

Basically we cannot use syntax like `stateArray[0]` in the template.

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to create another array (`mappedArray`), you can write a helper:

```
App.GetArrayItemHelper = Ember.Helper.helper(function(values) {
    var array = values[0], index = values[1];
    return array[index];
})
```

Then in your template:

```
<select id="state_list">
    {{#each stateArrays as |stateArray|}}
        <option value={{get-array-item stateArray 0}}>{{get-array-item stateArray 1}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that I love this technique, but you can access the individual elements on an array like this

```
{{#each stateArrays as |stateArray|}}
    <option value={{stateArray.[0]}}>{{stateArray.[1]}}</option>
  {{/each}}
```

[Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/1f2c428ede5c58a8dbca91298ccc03c3?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)

Saves you having to write extra code.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing about this functionality. It really _feels_ weird to use, but is the most straightforward technique to access an array specific element without adding any code to an Ember application. I couldn't find any example of this on Ember website, but do you know of any official reference about it?

Comment: No, I can't sorry.  Had a quick look, but couldn't see anything in the docs.  Plenty of reference to it in official channels like Github issues though, but only in passing.